# Can't receive toast notification in windows phone 8

Tags: notifications, windows-phone-8, push, toast

I'm having problems receiving toast notifications for a Windows Phone 8 application. I did all the steps required:

For the client side, I did this:

- Get the channelUri from MPNS
- Open the channel
- Bind to toast notifications

For the server side, I did this:

- Server is written in PHP using [this code](http://phpwindowsphonepush.codeplex.com/)
- Hard-coded the Channel Uri I got in the client app into the PHP code (for testing purposes)

However, when I send the notification from the server, the phone doesn't seem to receive it. 
Everything runs correctly on the server side and the curl library loads without problems.

Comment: Just a reminder, you can't receive toast while the app in running in the foreground just make sure your app in closed on in background.

Comment: Yes I close the app and wait for the toast to show but it doesn't. I'm thinking about the name and URL I gave when registering to the channel. Can those be the reason of this problem?

Comment: Do the response headers/status (that you should be able to see from Curl) shed any light.  See [Push Notification Service response codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941100(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: It turned out the problem was in the constructor of the channel. I'll post the answer. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this!

The problem was in my constructor of the channel. I was doing this to create a new channel:

```
httpChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyChannel","www.foobar.com");
```

This constructor should only be called in case of "Authenticated Mode" of push notifications, which requires registering your website and having a certificate.

Obviously, this wasn't my case as I was just testing the push system.

The solution was to create the channel using this:

```
httpChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel("MyChannel");
```

It's so misleading as the the official documentation of Windows Phone didn't mention this.